# grep a string between two single quotes using only grep function

Tags: bash, grep

Get a string between two single quotes using only grep function

```
 0x00000000: 00000000 0000000f 00320031 00340033 '........1.2.3.4.'
```

I want my output as ........1.2.3.4.

I tried `grep -o '\'[^\']*'`

but it is not working ?

Comment: Try this : `grep -o "'[^']*'" file` OR `sed -n "s/.*'\([^']*\)'.*/\1/p" file`

Comment: Why do you care if the answer uses grep or some other standard UNIX tool like `cut` or `sed` or `awk`? `cut` would be the obvious tool for this.

Comment: Thanks dude its working, but returning '........1.2.3.4.'   Now we can use echo "${'........1.2.3.4.'//" ' "}" to get .............1.2.3.4.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

bash does not allow you to embed single quotes inside a [single quoted](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Single-Quotes) string. Not even escaped.

You need `grep -o "'[^]'*"`

If you want to exclude the leading single quote, and if you use GNU grep, then

```
grep -oP "(?<=').*?(?=')"
```

Comment: Your first sentence is not entirely true, look at my answer.

Comment: technically, that's not a single quoted string: it's an [ANSI-C quoted](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting) string

Comment: I'd just updated my answer with that link! And although that is the best kind of correct, i think it is close enough to be considered the same for the purpose of the question.